# Display view content in SQL Server2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I display the content of all Views in a db in SQL Server 2008? Is there any new system views to do the same?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "check the content"? Check it for what? Check that it runs? Find certain columns?

Comment: I want to view the definition of all views in my db

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way using Management Studio is to:

1. Find the database in Management Studio
2. In the database, click on the Views folder on the left (officially called the Object Explorer) which should show you a list of the views on your right. If it doesn't, you want to go to the View menu and chose Object Details.
3. Select all your views.
4. Right-click on the selected views and choose "Script View As" -> Create To -> New Query Window

This will open a window with the View definition of everything you selected.

EDIT: If you want to query for all your view definitions can you do something like:

```
Select VIEW_DEFINITION
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
```

If you change your output to Text instead of Grid, it will given you a listing of all your views.

As gbn pointed out, if it's the schema you want and if some developer is crazy enough to make a view with more than 4k characters, the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views will return null for that view's schema. So, in that case using the system tables would be more appropriate. A variation of gbn's solution which is akin to what SMS does behind the scenes would be:

```
Select smv.definition
FROM sys.all_views AS v
    JOIN sys.sql_modules AS smv 
        ON smv.object_id = v.object_id
```

Comment: Thanks..can you share T-SQL script to display all view definition at once?

Comment: Done. You can query for them via the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS

Comment: which is better? sys.views or INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS?

Comment: sys.views is proprietary to SQL Server. The INFORMATION_SCHEMA views are supposed to be somewhat universal and thus if given the choice would be the preferred method. However, it really comes down to preference. IMO I find the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views to simpler to read.

Comment: @gbn Not true. If the view def is over 4K you will get a null instead. It will not truncate.

Comment: I will say that when you script a view in SMS, it uses a combination of various sys views (although not sys.views specifically) which I'm guessing are variants of what you'll get from sys.views.

Comment: NULL or truncate is equally bad... no?

Comment: @gbn. Perhaps not equally bad but still definitely undesired I grant you.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT
    O.name, SM.definition
FROM
    sys.objects O
    JOIN
    sys.sql_modules SM ON o.object_id = SM.object_id
WHERE
    o.type = 'V'
```

"INFORMATION_SCHEMA" has a column limit of nvarchar(4000) which will cause truncation of the view definition when you select it: don't use it

Comment: Not true. According the BOL: "If the length of definition is larger than nvarchar(4000), this column is NULL. Otherwise, this column is the view definition text." So you should never get truncation. If you have views over 4k that is another matter.

Comment: Maybe the documentation is outdated because I have a view whose definition is larger than 4000 and it is being truncated.

Comment: @Thomas: feel free to use INFORMATION_SCHEMA for your views as these are typically smaller. However, for stored procedures (which tend to be longer) then I would use sys.sql_modules. But why not use the same method for all code? In real life I want to be 100% sure I get correct data. The BOL datatype is still nvarchar(4000)

Answer (score 0):

Adding this sqlcmd script for others as the 4k limit was not fun.  Thanks to this thread.

```
-- :r meta_show_view_definition.sql
-- need user logon with ALTER permissions
-- :setvar ObjectName "<string>"
set nocount on

declare @sql varchar(max)
:out $(ObjectName).view.dump.sql

set @sql = '
select obj.name, sm.definition
from   sys.objects obj
join   sys.sql_modules sm  on  obj.object_id = sm.object_id
where
    obj.type = "V" and
    upper(obj.name) = upper("' + '$(ObjectName)' + '")' 

exec (@sql)
go

:out stdout
set nocount off
```